# Specific form of an Apell Hypergeometric function with two variables

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

The famous form of an Appell $F_1()$ with two variables looks something like

$F_{1}\left(a,b_1,b_2,c;x_1,x_2\right)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)}\int_{0}^{1}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-a-1}(1-tx_1)^{-b_1}(1-tx_2)^{-b_2}dt$

I found one confluent hypergeometric function $\Phi()$ that looks something like

$\Phi\left(a,b,c;x_1,x_2\right)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)}\int_{0}^{1}t^{a+N-2}e^{-Ntx_2}(1-t)^{c-a-1}(1-tx_1)^{-b}dt$

Based on the above functions, is there an Apell function $F_{1}()$ of the  following form:
$F_{1}\left(a,b_1,b_2,c;x_1,x_2\right)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)}\int_{0}^{1}t^{a+N-2}(1-t)^{c-a-1}(1-tx_1)^{-b_1}(1-tx_2)^{-b_2}dt$

Comment: I don't understand:  $a'=a+n,a=a'-n,c'=c+n,c=c'-n$  seems to replicate your first equation.